# How do I reverse a running animation?

Tags: android, animation

When the `Button` is touched, it starts a zoom animation.

```
Animation zoomIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.zoomin);
view.startAnimation(zoomIn);
```

The *zoomin.xml* code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillEnabled="true"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <scale
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.3"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.3"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="200"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"/>
</set>
```

But if the `Button` is released during this still running animation, it should reverse the animation from **this point in time**.

How can i achieve that?

Comment: Post the code of the `zoomin` animation please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ViewPropertyAnimator` to achieve something like this.

For example:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.yourButton);

button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        // adjust the scale and duration values according to your needs

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            v.animate().scaleX(2).scaleY(2).setDuration(2000);
        } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            v.animate().scaleX(1).scaleY(1).setDuration(2000);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That was the solution. I thought the PropertyAnimator would change the size of the view and would mess up the whole layout, but that was not the case.